# Maximum of tcp connection on windows

Tags: performance, tcp, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a high load application which spins in IIS in Windows Server 2012. How to determine how many simultaneius tcp connections can windows handle and how to increase it? I already change TcpNumConnections and MaxUserPort to maximum allowed values, and TcpTimedWaitDelay to minimum. It helps to increase throughput of VM, but is it possible to configure something for better perfomance? Does it depend on SynAttackProtection or something else? And what should be tcp autotuninglevel for maximum performance?

Comment: None of those changes help improve the throughput of the VM.

Comment: May be I said something incorrect, but I meant tcp throughput i.e. number of simultaneous tcp connections. Because when I have to many of them I start to receive errors like connection refused or connection reset. Actually  I'm trying to determine maximum possible number of such connections.